# to store thelist of coordinates columnwise in csv files

Tags: python, pandas, csv, col

I have a list of coordinates and I want to store them in columns
The list is like and they are created according to the loop so they keep on changing when the loop enters the next image.

```
CC = [ (113,254),(163,253),(230,252),......]
CC = [ (0,2128),(163,253),(229,252),......]
```

I used the below code to create the csv file and store it

```
with open( "XY.csv", "a") as out_file:
                out_string = ""
                out_string += str(simg_name)
                out_string +=  "," + ",".join([str(i) for i in CC])
                out_string += "\n"
                out_file.write(out_string)
```

But it stores like [image]

I want it to be and remove the "(" ")" also

[image]

Comment: can you try `pd.DataFrame(CC).to_csv('filename',index=False)` ?

Comment: I tried but I want to add `simg_name` name too and there are 10 images

Comment: It will be better if you can create a reproducible example in the question

Comment: Always provide a [mre], with **code, data, errors, current output, and expected output, as [formatted text](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting), [Not Screenshots](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/)**. It is likely the question will be down-voted and closed. You are discouraging assistance because no one wants to retype your data or code, and screenshots are often illegible. [edit] the question and **add text**. Please see [How to provide a reproducible copy of your DataFrame using `df.head(30).to_clipboard(sep=',')`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52413246).